# Assuming $\delta < 1$ in uniform continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

I recently was asked to show that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$. I couldn't find a nice $x,y \in (0, \infty)$ so that I could reach a contradiciton in my proof. I have seen that people sometimes assume $\delta < 1$. I did this in the proof and was able to arrive at $\frac{1}{\delta} > \varepsilon = 1$.

My question is it valid to assume that $\delta$ is small ($\delta < 1$) and arrive at a contradiction to show that my $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty).$ My thinking is that if $|x-y| < \delta$, then for any $\delta_1 \geq 1$, $|x-y| < \delta_1$ should hold.

Comment: Yes, it's valid. Considering only $\delta \in (0,1)$ loses no generality. It's not too hard to prove that one can equivalently define both continuity and uniform continuity assuming $\delta \in (0,1)$ rather than $\delta>0$.

Comment: If there is a $\delta\geq1$ that works, then so does $\delta=0.5$. So there is no problem with setting a positive upper bound for what $\delta$ can be.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall \epsilon>0\colon\exists \delta>0\colon \forall x,y\in\Bbb R\colon \bigl(|x-y|<\delta\to |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\bigr)$$
is equivalent to
$$\forall \epsilon>0\colon\exists 1>\delta>0\colon \forall x,y\in\Bbb R\colon \bigl(|x-y|<\delta\to |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\bigr).$$
The non-trivial direction follows because  $|x-y|<\delta\to |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ gets *weaker* if we make $\delta$ smaller.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the implications of it being weaker.

Comment: If I want to contradict then I want to show that $\exists \varepsilon > 0 : \forall \delta>0: \exists x,y \in D: |x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| \geq \varepsilon|$ and if I show for $\delta$ with an upper bound, I don't think it is an issue since it will be true for all $\delta$ greater than the bound.